# Ошибка при чтении данных из com-порта

Tags: python, com-порт

К компьютеру через com-порт (RS-232) подключено устройство, которое передает 10 байт данных. Первый байт информирует о том, что содержится в оставшихся 9-ти байтах, его значение всегда 0, 1 или 2. Данные передаются двумя способами: информация 1-ого и 2-ого типа передается в случайный момент времени, 0-ого типа - один раз в 10 секунд. Обрабатывается эта информация тоже по разному.

Я написала такой код для обработки информации на Python:

```
#Открываю порт
channel = serial.Serial('COM3', 19200)

#инструменты для обработки данных
i = 0
D = 16384
sp1 = np.zeros(D)
sp2 = np.zeros(D)

while i < 100000:

    i = i + 1
    
#Читаю 10 байт из порта
    x = bytearray(channel.read(10))

#В зависимости от значения первого байта выполняются разные действия

    if x[0] == 1:
        tdc1 = x[1]*256 + x[2]

        while j < D:
            if (tdc1 <= space[j * width] + width) and (tdc1 >= space[j * width] + 1):
                sp1[j] = sp1[j] + 1
                j = D
            j = j + 1
        j = 0
            

    if x[0] == 2:
        tdc2 = x[1]*256 + x[2]

        while j < D:
            if (tdc2 <= space[j * width] + width) and (tdc2 >= space[j * width] + 1):
                sp2[j] = sp2[j] + 1
                j = D
            j = j + 1
        j = 0
        
    if x[0] == 0:
        n1 = x[1]*65536 + x[2]*256 + x[3]
        n2 = x[4]*65536 + x[5]*256 + x[6]
        n0 = x[7]*65536 + x[8]*256 + x[9]
```

Проблема вот в чем: код работает нормально в течение некоторого времени, после чего данные начинают считываться неправильно: первый байт перестает быть первым и вся последовательность байт как будто сдвигается. То есть, в нормальном режиме данные приходят вот так: `01 37 98 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`, а после сбоя вот так: `00 00 01 37 98 00 00 00 00 00`. При этом позиция первого байта, как и момент, в который происходит сбой, после каждого нового запуска кода случайны. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

Порт не обязан отдавать все десять байт сразу. Не знаю, какую библиотеку Вы используете, но, вероятно, после `.read` можно узнать (да хоть по размеру `x`), сколько байт было прочитано, если `.read` вышло по таймауту . Если не 10 - храните то, что есть и складывайте новые байты туда же.

(Вообще более правильно иметь протокол со стартовыми и финишными последовательностями, да и читать асинхронно)

Comment: спасибо за ответ! Использую библиотеку serial. Попробовала поменять структуру принимаемых данных: теперь в конце ставится 11 бит со значением \n, а данные читаются с помощью `.readline()`, вроде помогло.